# Paddle with Nuxt/Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, paddle-paddle

Has anyone implemented Paddle with Nuxt?  Trying to run this within a Nuxt app page (component):

```
<script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Paddle.Setup({ vendor: 1234567 });
</script>
```

I have tried three ways unsuccessfully.

1. NPM with paddle-sdk

https://www.npmjs.com/package/paddle-sdk

Out of data dependencies and will not build on a modern project.  When installing npm i --save paddle-sdk, I get the following errors.  Some of these dependencies are not available via npm:

```
 WARN  in ./node_modules/paddle-sdk/node_modules/keyv/src/index.js                                                                   friendly-errors 09:02:21

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression                                                                    friendly-errors 09:02:21
                                                                                                                                     friendly-errors 09:02:21

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                                              friendly-errors 09:02:21

These dependencies were not found:                                                                                                   friendly-errors 09:02:21
                                                                                                                                     friendly-errors 09:02:21
* dns in ./node_modules/cacheable-lookup/index.js                                                                                    friendly-errors 09:02:21
* fs in ./node_modules/paddle-sdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/request-as-event-emitter.js, ./node_modules/paddle-sdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/utils/get-body-size.js
* net in ./node_modules/paddle-sdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/utils/timed-out.js                                                   friendly-errors 09:02:21
                                                                                                                                     friendly-errors 09:02:21
To install them, you can run: npm install --save dns fs net                                                                          friendly-errors 09:02:21
```

2. Nuxt Plugins

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/

Cannot create a nuxt plugin with a remote (third party) script, only local in the plugins directory.  Paddle from their website asks: "Please do not self-host Paddle.js, this will prevent you from receiving bug fixes and new features."

3. Head method

I can implement the script in the head method within the page, but I cannot execute methods from the script within the nuxt page.  In other words this works:

`<script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"></script>`

But this does not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Paddle.Setup({ vendor: 1234567 });
</script>
```

Here is my head portion of my .vue file:

```
 head: {
    script: [
      {
        hid: 'Paddle',
        src: 'https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js',
        async: true,
        defer: false
      }
    ]
  },
```

Anyone had any luck or alternative solutions?

Comment: What are the out of date dependencies? What errors do you get with method 1?

Comment: Did you import the script using `head()`? In the first method, Could you please share the plugin code?

Comment: @ImanShafiei I added the code here.

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee I added the dependency errors too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simulate your problem, I imported the script in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
head: {
    script: [{
        src: 'https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js',
    }]
}
```

And use it in my page:

```
mounted() {
    Paddle.Setup({ vendor: 1234567 });
}
```

Of course, It'll output `You must specify a valid Paddle Vendor ID`.

Comment: This loads only on the second visit to the site, can I force it to load during the initial page load?

Comment: Do you mean that when you refresh the page, the `Paddle` variable is undefined? I tested it, and it was working. Also, maybe you want to use `defer: true` or `async: true`. See this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp for more info.

Comment: No, only on a refresh does the Paddle CSS and button work.

Comment: Ok, I see now. It's because we put the initiator in the `mounted()`. When do you want to `Paddle` initiate? I think you can put the initiator in a method and call it when you want. If you have more information, I'll be able to help you more.

Comment: I moved it to beforeCreated and will see if that helps.  Thank you for your assistance.